# Add labels to JSON with Jackson

Tags: java, json, dictionary, jackson

I have a `Map<String,Integer>`

that I want in the following form `[{text: String, count: Integer},{text: String2, count: Integer2},...]`

I know how to do this stuff with comprehensions in python but never used Jackson before for java, which I need to sue now.

I've done this to convert the map to Json

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
try {
    System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(myMap));
    //(looks like {"word":1,"word2":2,"word3":5}) (so I need to add a label text:
    // before each word a label weight before each number and put each word/number
    // block in a separate {})
    } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: If you go with the way `ObjectMapper` is currently converts to JSON, it will be much easier to put back into a `Map` from JSON. Otherwise, you'll have to do custom `Map` -> JSON and JSON to `Map` everywhere.

Comment: uh well i'm just doing this once in the end of my code, i just need a string of a certain format to pass somewhere, not a map, so i want to convert from the map to the string (i guess technically it doesn't "have to be" json)

Answer (score 2):

Algorithm is simple:

1. Create POJO class with two properties: **text** and **count**.
2. Convert `Map<String, Integer>` into List of POJO instances.
3. Convert result List into JSON

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure where to start as I've never used this before, but this will be a good starting point!

Comment: It's really easy. Try to implement it.